# Перезаписываются данные объекта, в поля которого ничего не записывалось

Tags: java, методы, static

Здравствуйте.
Недавно начал изучать Java, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой.

Есть класс `Vector` (он огромный, скопирую предмет вопроса. Пояснение по логике после кода):

```
public class Vector {
    private int size; //размерность
    private double[] vectorComponents; /компоненты

public void sum(Vector vector) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.getSize(); i++) {
            this.vectorComponents[i] += vector.vectorComponents[i];
        }
    }

public static Vector vectorSum(Vector vector1, Vector vector2) {
    boolean isVector1 = vector1.getSize() >= vector2.getSize();

    Vector resultVector = new Vector(isVector1 ? vector1 : vector2);
    resultVector.sum(isVector1 ? vector2 : vector1);

    return resultVector;
}
```

Пояснение:
Нужно сложить 2 вектора и получить в результате третий. Вектора могут быть разной размерности.Поэтому:

В `vectorSum` (который возвращает `resultVector`) выбираем вектор с большей размерностью.

Копируем выбранный вектор в `resultVector` (существует конструктор копирования `publuc Vector(Vector)`).

Вызываем у `resultVector` нестатичесий метод `sum` и передаём в него вектор с меньшей размерностью.

Возвращаем нужный вектор.

Проблема в том, что если я в `Main` вызываю:

```
Vector vector5 = new Vector(new double[]{5, 10, 15});
Vector vector6 = new Vector(new double[]{20, 25, 30});
Vector vector7 = Vector.vectorSum(vector5, vector6);

System.out.println("Сумма: " + vector5.toString() + " + " + vector6.toString() + " = " + vector7.toString());
```

То получаю:

> Сумма: [25.0, 35.0, 45.0] + [20.0, 25.0, 30.0] = [25.0, 35.0, 45.0]

То есть первый вектор перезаписывается по какой - то причине.
Смотрел по отладке. Всё работает вроде как хорошо:

1. В `resultVector` корректно записывается `vector1`;
2. В `resultVector.sum` передаётся `vector2`;
3. В `sum` всё покомпонентно складывается правильно и на протяжении всей работы метода `vector`(переданный) вообще никак не меняется(меняется `this.vector`). Но после выхода из метода переданный вектор ВНЕЗАПНО из 5;10;15 становится 25;35;45.
   Сломал себе голову вообщем. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Upd:
Конструктор копирования:

```
public Vector(Vector vectorFromCopy) {
        this.size = vectorFromCopy.size;
        this.vectorComponents = vectorFromCopy.vectorComponents;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А все просто. Массив в жабе - это объект и каждая переменная не новая копия массива, а ссылка на один и тот-же массив.
Другими словами, когда ты выполняешь этот код: `this.vectorComponents = vectorFromCopy.vectorComponents;`, что старый, что новый вектор, ссылаются на один и тот-же массив.

Используй этот способ: `Arrays.copyOf(source, source.length);`

Comment: Заработало.
Спасибо. Заодно еще раз про ссылочные типы прочитал.=)